# How to display results from XML file on grid view C#?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

`  this  is part of my code:

```
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            int gthan = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            foreach (XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("/employees/employee/salary"))
            {

                int curr = Int32.Parse(n.InnerText);
                if (curr <gthan)
                { noe++;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("number of employees" + +noe);}
```

` 
I made some functions preformed in XML file table like bringing maximum salary and so on but how to tell the program to display the child that have the maximum salary on grid view in windows form application?

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

you could do the following

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("Path to your xml file");
dgvSalary.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dgvSalary.Refresh();
```

In this example you would want to have a DataTable Declared at the Class level

```
//dtSearch is a DataTable that was declared at the class level as 
public DataTable dtSearch = null; 
//you can populate the dtSearch with the ds.Tables[0];
dtSearch = ds.Tables[0];
dv = new DataView(dtSearch); //create a DataView in memory
dv.RowFilter = "Salary < 1000";
//bind the DataGridView to dv 
dgvSalary.DataSource = dv;
dgvSalary.Refresh();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this display whole table and i did this before but i wanted when i use function to display for example employees that their salary less than 1000$ rows in grid view not all employees

Comment: you can still do this by using the `.RowFilter` method to Filter the datatable  creating an new instance of `DataView` object this is also very simple I can send an example if you need it

Comment: oh yes please send me an example i will be thankful because i am beginner in C#

Comment: excuse me but how i could do this and by doing this that mean i wont read the data from XML file any more because XML file  is necessary for the program

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding this can be done as long as you have the Salary node in the xml it will always work no matter how many Rows..

Comment: now what if i want user to decide the value he want  to search for like he want all employees they get less than 2000$ and show the result in grid view

Comment: then you code for this to be dynamic based on a dropdown or a Textbox this is still possible. you need to understand how to use as well as pass parameters.. why don't you try something then post code where you are having issues doing this.. Dynamic coding is not difficult in regards to passing a parameter or list of parameters..

Comment: don't put code in comments.. if you have current code you want others to look at, edit your original question and post it there.. I am not going to try and read your code in comments..